# Saving Hex string into sql as varbinary using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, encoding

I am trying to replace a table insert that currently occurs via a stored procedure to a very simple Entity Framework command. The problem is that the data starts as an encrypted string, and is then turned into a HEX string before being handed to the stored procedure. The stored procedure expects a `varbinary(50)` and presumably is simply converting the HEX string to `varbinary` on the fly.

I cannot simply pass Entity Framework the HEX string - it knows it is supposed to be `byte[]`!

What I cannot figure out is how to convert the hex string into a `byte[]` that will be identical to whatever SQL Server is doing on the backend.

I have determined the encoding SQL Server uses, and am able to convert the byte[] back to the encrypted string I started with using:

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytes)
```

Is there an Entity Framework trick, or some other option to simply continue letting SQL Server do the conversion? I cannot change the data types in SQL Server, and I would prefer not to create a dummy stored procedure that simply takes in a string and returns `varbinary`.

For those interested, the an example hex string generated is `0x1C3307260C18`. 
For the purposed of this discussion, it should not matter how this string is generated- and since it is security related code I can't post the exact process that creates it.

What I need to know is, once this string has been created,  how do I replicate SQL Server's process of converting this string into it's `varbinary` equivalent using C#? Incidentally, when viewing the table in SQL Server, the binary data is rendered in this exact hex form. So, passing the string `0x1C3307260C18` to SQL results in it being stored as `varbinary`, and it renders in queries exactly the same: `0x1C3307260C18`.

Comment: Can you show how your encrypted string is _turned into a HEX string_?

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(hexString)` ?

Comment: can you show the portion of the stored procedure that relates to this, so we can understand what "conversion" you are doing?

Comment: `GetBytes` does not create a "HEX String" it creates an array of bytes.  Just pass that into your  stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the original hex string back through `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytes)`, it's obvious that the original code doesn't actually use the binary representation of the hex string - it simply converts the *text* to `varbinary`!

That probably isn't what the author intended.

But, you can get the exact same thing by just doing the reverse - `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(hexstring)`.

The problem probably originated by quoting the hex string - `0x1C3307260C18` is a perfectly fine `varbinary` value, but `'0x1C3307260C18'` is a `varchar` - when converted to `varbinary`, it simply converts using string->byte conversion rules (so basically just applying the given encoding).

If you want to keep the "wrong" code, that's just fine, and does the same thing the SQL server does (assuming the server's colation corresponds to ISO-8859-1). If you want to fix it and actually save the binary string `0x1C3307260C18`, you'll need to convert it a bit harder (or just fix your decryption method to return `byte[]` instead of `string` :)):

```
Func<char, int> getHex = c =>
 {
   var p = c - '0';
   if (p < 10) return p;

   return (char.ToUpperInvariant(c) - 'A') + 10;
 };

var hexString = "0x1C3307260C18";
if (!hexString.StartsWith("0x")) { return null; } // Fail in some way

var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2 - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
  bytes[i] = 
   (byte)
    (
     (getHex(hexString[(i + 1) * 2]) << 4) 
     | getHex(hexString[(i + 1) * 2 + 1])
    );
}

bytes.Select(i => i.ToString("X2")).Dump();
```

Usually, it would be better to use `Convert.ToByte(str, 16)`, but it's probably a waste to do so many `Substring`s for something as simple as parsing hex strings :)

The last line is just there to verify it works, of course; You'll also want to make the `getHex` function a method, rather than keeping it anonymous. And depending on your requirements, you might want to add aditional error checking - e.g. `getHex` should never return outside of the 0-15 range etc.

Comment: I may not have been clear in the original- Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytes) does not return the hex string- it actually returns the original encrypted string that was used to generate the Hex string. The string is not hex, but a collection of random looking control chars. Like I said, it is encrypted...

Comment: @RickM Ah, okay, that makes a lot more sense :) In that case, use the helper function I've posted as part of my answer - it will actually transform the whole hex string into a `byte[]`.